# Mysql Alter table using concat

Tags: mysql, concatenation

These SQLs should be give same result? Second one gives an error (SQL Error 1064).

```
Correct :          ALTER TABLE table1 TRUNCATE PARTITION d20; 
Does not work   :  ALTER TABLE table1 TRUNCATE PARTITION concat('d', '20');
```

Actually I stuck on truncate table with respect to day of month, (ie today is 25th) execute

i was planned sql like below, but does not work

```
ALTER TABLE table1 TRUNCATE PARTITION DAYOFMONTH(now());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they shouldn't. `TRUNCATE PARTITION` accepts a partition name, which is not a string.

**UPD**:

You still can create and perform dynamic sql queries using `PREPARE` + `EXECUTE`

Comment: Thanks this is sol'n for problem but I have a constraint. SQL should be simple that only one line (statement). If it is possible done by  one step i am very glad

Comment: @erdinc: unfortunately it is not. Only dynamic sql.